# CentOS 7 ASP not working

Tags: httpd, centos7, mono

I have set up a CentOS 7 VM running ISPConfig 3 on port 8080, httpd on 80 and a few other services like Dovecot etc..

I'm trying yo set up the VM so that it can display .aspx pages, but for some reason I keep getting a 503 error.
It seems that I have installed all the needed modules etc (what I could find on internet).

When I try to access the ASPX website I get the 503 error and in the httpd error log I get the following:

```
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Should be something like [[hostname:]port:]VPath:realpath
  at Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer.AddApplicationsFromCommandLine (System.String applications) <0x40f7e3c0 + 0x0033f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer:AddApplicationsFromCommandLine (string)
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean v_quiet) <0x40f233e0 + 0x00563> in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server:RealMain (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.Main (System.String[] args) <0x40f22d70 + 0x000e3> in <filename unknown>:0
[Tue Dec 08 14:12:06.203166 2015] [:error] [pid 9330] Failed to connect to mod-mono-server after several attempts to spawn the process.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> [pid 9330] Failed to connect to mod-mono-server after several attempts to spawn the process.

This is your problem. Now you need to figure out what that means.

- Check your mono server is running.
- Check your mono config
- Check your httpd config.
- Find and check the mono logs
- Take a peak at the /var/log/audit/audit.log and check for related SELinux issues

Comment: I made sure the server is running but the same error is being shown. I don't think it's a problem with the server not running though :)